# Reading special characters from Latin 1 Microsoft SQL database with php

Tags: php, sql-server, encoding, utf-8

I have a predefined Microsoft SQL database. The database collation is specified as SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.

The database version is: SQL Server Express 10.0.1600.22

Some of the tables have values with special characters (I assume UTF-8). I am reading these tables with php mssql, and I end up with question marks in the output `????? ???? ?????`

I have tried playing with `ini_set('mssql.charset','utf8')`, with different encoding values such as `windows-cp1251`, `windows-cp1252` with no luck.

I am not sure how to proceed with this? I guess that I need the equivalent of MySQL `SET NAMES UTF-8`, but I am not sure how to do that in MSSQL. Any ideas?

Converting the tables to utf8 unfortunately is not an option. The field type is nvarchar(250)

Answer (score 0):

A lot of missing information here; for example, the type of the field in the database (varchar, nvarchar???).

Try converting your field to an unicode field if it's stored as a varchar field; for example:

Select cast (field1 as nvarchar(200)) as field1, ...

Also, even if the database collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, each field can have its own specific collation. The database collation is mainly the default collation to be used when you don't specify the collation for a field.

Comment: just checked, the field type is nvarchar(250)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error could be in a variety of places.  The first thing to check is to make sure that your web page can display the extended characters correctly on your web site pages by writing some; for example:

```
<html>...<p>é</p>...
```

Of course, if unecessary to try with an HTML entities such as `&eacute;` for doing these tests because the problem is not there; you must use real encoded extended characters.

After that, you can check that your extended characters have been correctly stored in your database by checking their numerical values with the function `Unicode().`  You can also check that you can write an extended character using the `NChar()` function; for example:

```
Select Unicode (substring (field1, 1, 1)), Unicode (N'é'), NChar(233), ...
```

The Unicode() and NChar() functions are standard Microsoft SQL functions.

It has been many years since the last time that I have coded with PHP, however, from what I recall, the default values for the configuration were sufficient for displaying any extended characters coming from a SQL-Server database using a nvarchar or ntext field.

Answer (score 0):

Use the connection option: "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8" as stated at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc626307(v=sql.105).aspx

It worked for me. No further conversion needed.